# modify value returned by SELECT with MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want do such as this:

```
$username0 = $_POST["nkn"];
$username1 = strtoupper($username0);
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE strtoupper(username) = '".$username1."'";
```

What's the right way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You mean  to modify and update the values ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: use a case insensitive collation where you don't need any index killing functions.

Comment: and beware sql injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = '".$username1."'";
```

In mysql the is the function [UPPER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) to convert the string in upper case.